# Create Linux install for Qt application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt4, debian, qt-installer

I just made a great program with Qt Creator.  I'm very pleased with myself.  How do I move it from my desktop to my laptop?

So, the best way would be an installer right?  And for Ubuntu, that's a debian package right?

How do I do that?  Has someone done this and could they share the template files for QT 4.5?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run the application `foo` you created on the machine *desktop* on another machine *laptop*, then simply

1. copy the binary, for example via `scp`
2. run `ldd foo` on *laptop*
3. install the library package for all missing libaries
4. go back to 2. and repeat until you have missing libaries.

This can be done in minutes.

A Debian package would automate steps 2) and 3) and provide you `Depends:` so that upon installation proper libraries are added, if needed.   But if you just want to go from one machine to another (using the same distro) then creating a package is overkill.

Comment: Quick and easy, but can lead to a dependency hell, which however is not a problem with all those apt-get's around :)

Answer (score 2):

No first hand experience. But, for Ubuntu, creating a Debian package should suffice your needs here. I just came across [Debian Package Builder](http://www.qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Debreate+%28Kde%29+-+Debian+Package+Builder?content=104257). HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Qt Creator itself is packaged using [BitRock InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com), you may want to try that